# Connectivity error and java.long.nullpointer error

Tags: java, mysql, swing

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.swing.*;

public class loginscreen {


JFrame frame =new JFrame("Login Screen");
JLabel username =new JLabel("username:");
JLabel pword = new JLabel("password:");
JTextField t1 =new JTextField(15);
JTextField p1=new JTextField(15);
JButton button =new JButton("login");
Connection conn=null;
public void display()
{
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    JPanel panel =new JPanel();
    panel.add(username);
    panel.add(t1);
    panel.add(pword);
    panel.add(p1);
    panel.add(button);
    frame.add(panel);

    frame.setSize(300,300);
     frame.setVisible(true);
}
public void connection()
{

button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
    try{
         try{
         String url ="jdbc:mysql56://localhost:3306/";
         String dbname="test1";
         String driver="com.mysql56.jdbc.Driver";
         String uname="root";
         String password="root";
         Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
          conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbname,uname,password);

         }catch(Exception exe)
         {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "connection error");
         }
        String query="select*from login where username=? and pwd=? ";

           PreparedStatement pst= conn.prepareStatement(query);
           pst.setString(1,t1.getText());
           pst.setString(2,p1.getText());
           ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();
           if (rs.next())
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username and Password correct");
            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "invalid username and password");
            }
           rs.close();
           pst.close();
           conn.close();


          }catch(Exception ex )
          {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
          }

}

});
}


public static void main(String args[])
{
    loginscreen login=new loginscreen();
    login.display();
    login.connection();
}}
```

I'm getting connection error and null pointer error. Please help me to correct them.

Comment: Can you share the error you are seeing?

Comment: `conn` is probably null

Comment: i am getting class not found error

Comment: help me to correct my error

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this connection error because the class name of the driver is invalid. So, the exception (ClassNotFoundException) is thrown.

I tried with `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` instead of `com.mysql56.jdbc.Driver` and it is working fine.

Moreover, due to this exception connection object will not be created. So it will be null. Thus, getting NullPointerException. Once the driver is loaded successfully with the above mentioned driver name, this NPE will also be solved.

You will have to change the driver name at both the places, one in assigning `url` and another in assigning `driver`.

You should also check whether the connection object is null or not to verify whether you have successfully get the connection or not